# Is the Windows Service installed or not?

Tags: command-line, windows-services

Simple explanation:

1. Installed a Windows Service using sc create. It appeared to work
2. Tried to run the service using sc start. Message: "The specified service does not exist as an installed service."
3. Run sc create again.  "The Specified Service already exists."

What gives?  Have I created a Schrodinger's Service?

Comment: Can you post the `sc create` and `sc start` commands you used?  Are you able to see the service listed in the local services?

Comment: I can see the service under the 'Services' application.  I am running 'sc start Notifications'. THe create command was 'sc create Notifications displayname="<The name I wanted for display>" binpath="<ThePath to the service>"'

Comment: Run `sc query state= all | findstr /I "SERVICE_NAME: STATE"`. Check if the service name is present in the list.